# Using CefSharp with Owin TestServer

Tags: c#, owin, chromium-embedded, katana, cefsharp

Due to potential firewall limitations and the need to have many instances of my app that cannot be competing for ports, I would like to use the Microsoft.Owin.Testing.TestServer class to create an in-memory web server that will serve requests to an embedded CefSharp browser (either WPF or Winforms is fine).

I can create the TestServer with no issues. How can I configure the CefSharp WebBrowser control to use that Test Server rather than using the standard OS network stack?

If I was forming my own requests, I would either use the HttpClient provided by the TestServer or create a new HttpClient using the TestServer's handler. Is there any equivalent functionality in CefSharp WebBrowser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can intercept requests and fulfill them yourself. If you implement `IResourceHandlerFactory` then subsequently `IResourceHandler` (Just return a new instance of your custom `IResourceHandler` in `IResourceHandlerFactory.GetResourceHandler`)

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp/IResourceHandlerFactory.cs#L22

A new instance of your custom `ResourceHandler` will be instantiated for every request. It's relatively simple to process the request in an `async` fashion, just invoke your request in `ProcessRequestAsync`, when it's complete fill a local stream with the data execute `callback.Continue()`, return the stream and populate the response in `GetResponse`. I like to wrap `callback` in a `using` statement as it wraps a managed resource and should be explicitly disposed of.

You can see a basic example at https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp.Example/CefSharpSchemeHandler.cs#L92 (Doesn't make network requests, the principal is the same though)

Comment: This works nicely, thanks. A quick note for anyone else reading this. Just be sure to assign an instance of the new ResourceHandlerFactory to the ResourceHandlerFactory property of the WebBrowser control. If you're using WPF, this will most likely be in the constructor of your XAML code behind, or potentially in a behavior.

Comment: Basic working example https://github.com/amaitland/CefSharp.Owin/blob/master/CefSharp.Owin/OwinResourceHandler.cs Full disclosure first time dabbling with OWIN, so feedback welcome.