# Using CefSharp's ResourceHandlerFactory with SignalR/WebSockets

Tags: c#, owin, chromium-embedded, katana, cefsharp

I'm following the instructions in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34624015/using-cefsharp-with-owin-testserver), which shows how to configure CefSharp with a ResourceHandlerFactory to avoid using the standard OS network stack:

```
var browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("<html file here>")
{
     ResourceHandlerFactory = myResourceHandlerFactory, //implements IResourceHandlerFactory                
};
```

This works well for static files, but I'm unable to handle WebSocket requests from SignalR. The client sends these requests, but they never appear in the `GetResourceHandler` method of my `IResourceHandlerFactory`, which accepts all other requests.

How can I handle WebSocket requests from CefSharp in-memory like this?

**Edit with solution:** Using amaitland's suggestion, I was able to implement `ISchemeHandlerFactory` to intercept WebSocket requests. My Cef initialization now looks like this:

```
var settings = new CefSettings();
settings.RegisterScheme(new CefCustomScheme { SchemeName = "ws", SchemeHandlerFactory = new OwinSchemeHandlerFactory() });
Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

...and my OwinSchemeHandlerFactory just implements the Create method that returns an `IResourceHandler`:

```
public IResourceHandler Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request)
{
    // return myResourceHandlerFactory.GetResourceHandler();
}
```

Comment: Does it work for general requests? At a guess you'll have to use an `ISchemeHandlerFactory` and register for the `ws` and/or `wss` schemes. See the main `CefSharp` project for examples.

Comment: @amaitland: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction - that's exactly what I was looking for. I'm now able to intercept WebSocket requests using ISchemeHandlerFactory. (I'm not sure the best way to do this, but if you post your comment as an answer, I can mark it as the accepted answer.)

Comment: Done, feel free to propose any edits you think are relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use an `ISchemeHandlerFactory` you can register a scheme to intercept  the `ws` and/or `wss` schemes.

Comment: Great, thank you! I edited my question to include some of the code I used.