# cefsharp settings.RegisterScheme("wss") does not work

Tags: websocket, cefsharp

I've registered wss-scheme handler. WS was created (see [devtools screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHBQA.jpg)) but SchemeHandlerFactory.Create() never fired!

```
public class SchemeHandlerFactory : ISchemeHandlerFactory
{
    IResourceHandler ISchemeHandlerFactory.Create(IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, string schemeName, IRequest request) {...}
}
```

Comment: It's not possible to intercept web sockets using a scheme handler factory.

Comment: @amaitland thanks! is it even possible? I mean WS sniffing and injection.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: You can probably do it in JavaScript. https://github.com/skepticfx/wshook#easily-intercept-and-modify-websocket-requests-and-message-events

Comment: @amaitland thanks! is this solution deprecated [using-cefsharps-resourcehandlerfactory-with-signalr-websockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512999/using-cefsharps-resourcehandlerfactory-with-signalr-websockets)?

Comment: In theory you can use the DevTools protocol to obtain the websocket payload  https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#event-webSocketFrameReceived You cannot modify the request/responses