# Intercept WebSocket requests from CefSharp

Tags: websocket, cefsharp

any ideas on how to intercept WebSocket requests from CefSharp?
I used the solution described in the following link, but Create method never get fired
[Using CefSharp's ResourceHandlerFactory with SignalR/WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512999/using-cefsharps-resourcehandlerfactory-with-signalr-websockets)
could someone help me with this?

Comment: That post is 6yrs old and is no longer valid. You can try a JavaScript based solution like https://github.com/skepticfx/wshook#easily-intercept-and-modify-websocket-requests-and-message-events