# Websocket not working in CEFSharp project

Tags: c#, cefsharp, chromium-embedded

I have a pretty basic cefsharp project that open a website just like a browser.

My website have some **secure websocket** connections those work perfectly in normal browser, but when I try to run the same website in cefsharp, it never connects to socket server.

> After few seconds of Connecting it Disconnect...

I was trying to use this way [Using CefSharp's ResourceHandlerFactory with SignalR/WebSockets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35512999/using-cefsharps-resourcehandlerfactory-with-signalr-websockets)

But the problem is, I don't want to intercept websocket request. I just want them to be able to run on the website.

**Xaml Code::**

```
<wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser x:Name="Browser" >
                <behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    <behaviours:HoverLinkBehaviour x:Name="HoverLinkBehaviour"/>
                </behaviors:Interaction.Behaviors>
            </wpf:ChromiumWebBrowser>
```

C# Code::

```
 // Request Handler (add cloudflare service auth token in header)
 Browser.RequestHandler = new CloudflareServiceToken(
                                                    "Public Token",
                                                    "Secret Key"
                                                    );


            Browser.Address = Config.HOME_URL;
```

**My Request Handler**

```
class CloudflareServiceTokenHandler : ResourceRequestHandler
    {
        public CloudflareServiceTokenHandler(string key, string secret)
        {
            _key = key;
            _secret = secret;
        }

        private string _key, _secret;

        protected override CefReturnValue OnBeforeResourceLoad(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, IRequestCallback callback)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_key) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_secret))
            {
                var headers = request.Headers;
                headers["CF-Access-Client-Id"] = $"{_key}";
                headers["CF-Access-Client-Secret"] = $"{_secret}";
                request.Headers = headers;
                return CefReturnValue.Continue;
            }
            else return base.OnBeforeResourceLoad(chromiumWebBrowser, browser, frame, request, callback);
        }

    }
    class CloudflareServiceToken : RequestHandler
    {
        public CloudflareServiceToken(string CF_KEY, string CF_SECRET)
        {
            _key = CF_KEY;
            _secret = CF_SECRET;
        }

        private string _key, _secret;

        protected override IResourceRequestHandler GetResourceRequestHandler(IWebBrowser chromiumWebBrowser, IBrowser browser, IFrame frame, IRequest request, bool isNavigation, bool isDownload, string requestInitiator, ref bool disableDefaultHandling)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_key) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_secret)) return new CloudflareServiceTokenHandler(_key, _secret);
            else return base.GetResourceRequestHandler(chromiumWebBrowser, browser, frame, request, isNavigation, isDownload, requestInitiator, ref disableDefaultHandling);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What version are you using? Does it work if you comment out your RequestHandler? Check DevTools for errors

Comment: @amaitland brooo! You are great, it's working now... but can you please gimme some other way to have websocket enabled as well as to add customer header in HTTP request ?

Comment: @amaitland I just added my custom request handler.. please have a look at that

Comment: What scheme is your websocket using? WS/WSS? Best guess is that you are adding the headers to the websocket handshake which is not supported by CEF causing the request to fail. I'm guessing as I don't have much information to go by.

Comment: As an alternative you should be able to use DevTools to append extra headers to every request. See https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/4112340e48467c93ffc7f606d5861015e79d29bb/CefSharp.Test/DevTools/DevToolsClientFacts.cs#L273